# A suitable corpus for training skip-though vectors

Tags: dataset, natural-language, word-embeddings

For training a variant of the notion of skip-though vectors, I need a long corpus of **consecutive** (related) sentences. The original skip-thought paper has used BookCorpus, but it is no longer available. Is there a similar dataset available online? I know Gutenberg project, but unfortunately its data is notoriously difficult to pre-process, and I'd also prefer more contemporary texts.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- [Common Crawl corpus](http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/): consists of 145 TB of data from 1.81 billion webpages as of August 2015
- http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2018/pdf/889.pdf: see Table 1 for several summarization corpora, which consist of texts with consecutive (related) sentences.